# Remote port forwarding through EC2 not working, though address is in use

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, port, port-forwarding, troubleshooting

I have a remote machine running a server which I'd like access to locally. However, I can only SSH into the machine, not use any other ports.

I booted up an Amazon EC2 instances and opened all its ports. The plan is to set up a remote tunnel from the machine to the ec2 instance.

On the remote machine, the server is working:

```
$ links http://localhost:5555/foobs
```

This accesses the `foobs` page correctly. On EC2, I can access port 5555 if a server is hosted there:

```
$ echo really > index.html
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5555
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 5555 ...
```

Then, from my local browser: http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5555/ gives me the "really" page.

However, if I do port forwarding, from the machine:

```
$ ssh -R 5555:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5555 -i keys/key.pem user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then pointing my browser at http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5555/ does *not* get me the page. The app that uses it gives `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. However, the port *is* being used. If from the ssh shell that's doing the forwarding I try to run the server on the same port:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5555
...
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

What gives? I am not the biggest networking wizard, as might be evident.

Comment: So why does the EC2 instance need to be involved?

Comment: @EEAA: I can only connect to the remote machine via the SSH port. I can't open any ports on the remote machine. But I need to connect to a server running on the remote machine. I also can't SSH from the remote machine to my local machine.

Comment: You're making this far too complicated. See my below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your local machine:

```
$ ssh -L5555:localhost:5555 user@remote-machine.example.com
```

Then you'll have access to port 5555 on the remote machine from your local system. Just point your browser to `http://localhost:5555/`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I should have seen it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to enable Port Forwarding in Amazon Elastic Load Balancer for the port 5555. Do you use ELB in front of your instance?